# SQLAlchemy select only one column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Try to select one column from pg_shadow table the following way:

```
role_tbl = Table('pg_shadow', MetaData(engine), autoload=True)
db.query(role_tbl.c.passwd).filter_by(usename='name')
```

And get an error:

> *** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'class_'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
role_tbl.select([role_tbl.c.passwd]).where(username=='name').execute().fetchall()
```

Or probably there is no such column in this table.

You can check it by printing all columns

```
print role_tbl.columns
```

P.S.
And also you should use one instance of metadata: MetaData(engine) (it should store information about all tables)

Answer (score 2):

The error is the result of having [no entity in the query](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by):

> The keyword expressions are extracted from the primary entity of the query, or the last entity that was the target of a call to `Query.join()`.

where an entity is a mapped class, or the `Table` object, but you're querying a single column. The proper way to filter would be:

```
db.query(role_tbl.c.passwd).filter(role_tbl.c.usename == 'name')
```

In a more recent version of SQLAlchemy the error is:

```
NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select only one column you can use [`Select.with_only_columns`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns):

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Text
meta = MetaData()
table = Table('user', meta,
              Column("name", Text),
              Column("full_name", Text))
stmt = (table.select()
        .with_only_columns([table.c.name])
       )
print(stmt)

# SELECT "user".name
# FROM "user"
```